# Probability question Suppose that an employee arrives late 10% of the time ...

Tags: probability

Suppose that an employee arrives late 10% of the time, leaves early 20% of the
time, and both arrives late and leaves early 5% of the time. What is the probability that
on a given day that employee will either arrive late or leave early (or both)?

Attempt:

```
Given:
-Arrives late 10% of the time
-Leaves early 20% of the time
-Arrives late and leaves early 5% of the time
```

Want:

What is the probability that
on a given day that employee will either **arrive late or leave early (or both)**?

I really am unsure how to go about this. I would normally add them together and I would get 35% of the time which doesn't sound right. I think I have to use something like theorem of total probability $$P(B) = P(A_1 \cap B) + P(A_2 \cap B) + \cdots$$

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion implies that $Pr(A\cup B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cap B)$

Comment: 25% seems about right. Which is what this principle gives. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the $5\%$ more than once because the $15\%$ and $20\%$ overlap by $5\%$. If you are both late arriving and leaving early on the same day $5\%$ of the time, then you are "only" late arriving $(10 - 5) = 5\%$ and you are "only" leaving early $(20 - 5) = 15\%$. Now when you add these three percentages you get $25\%$.